# Index sql join with ThinkingSphinx

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

I am new on thinking sphinx I don't find any solution that help me to index left join using thinking sphinx.

This is my query that I want to index in sphinx

```
Company.joins("left join award_judges on award_judges.company_id = companies.id").where("companies.company_type = 'investor' AND (award_judges.award_id = 6 OR award_judges.award_id IS NULL)").select("companies.id,companies.name, award_judges.judge_application_type,award_judges.judgement_status").order("award_judges.judge_application_type, award_judges.judgement_status")
```

where as the association in my Company Model is

```
has_many :award_judges
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to associations within your index, and also have `WHERE` conditions, in your index definition:

```
indexes award_judges.judgement_status, :as => :judgement_statuses

where "companies.company_type = 'investor' AND (award_judges.award_id = 6 OR award_judges.award_id IS NULL)"
```

Comment: so you are saying that we can define where clause in indexing block?

Comment: Yes, if you want that clause to apply to the data that Sphinx indexes. If you want it to apply as filters on specific searches, though, then you'll need attributes to filter on instead.